# How do I pass a filename between two Jenkins builds?

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a python test script running in Jenkins that dynamically creates a json file in the script.

What I would like to happen is that dynamically generated filename gets put into a parameter and sent to another jenkins job triggered after the first finishes.

I have looked at sites like this: https://itisatechiesworld.wordpress.com/jenkins-related-articles/jenkins-configuration/jenkins-passing-a-parameter-from-one-job-to-another/

Where they are passing the Jenkins made "environment variables" via the Parameterized Trigger Plugin, however, these are variables that are predefined in Jenkins. How do I store and pass a variable along that I dynamically create?

Comment: Have you tried setting it as an environment variable?

Comment: How can you set it if it's being dynamically generated at the time of the jenkins build?

Comment: What do you mean? Set it when it's known.

Answer (score -1):

From [the plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin):

> The parameters section can contain a combination of one or more of the following:
>
> - a set of predefined properties
> - **properties from a properties file read from the workspace of the triggering build**
> - the parameters of the current build

So create such a properties file and use it as a parameter for your chained build.